# Symfony - Form with multiple entity objects

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm running Symfony 3.4 LTS and I have an entity `Attribute`:

```
<?php

class Attribute
{

    private $id;
    private $code;
    private $value;
    private $active;

    // My getters and setters
```

Below the database table:

[image]

I would like to get, in a form, all the rows with `code == 'productstatus'`. I tried:

```
<?php

$attributes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Attribute::class)->findBy(['code' => 'productstatus']);
// $attributes contains array with 3 objects 'Attribute'
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($attributes);
$form->add('value', TextType::class);
$output = $form->getForm()->createView();
```

If I dump() the `$output` var in Twig:

[image]

... I'm unable to make a loop to display the 3  fields with values.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Result :

[image]

My goal is to allow the user to edit all the values of a specific attributes in the same form (or multiple forms, but in the same page). I already tried with CollectionType without success.

Comment: I'm lost and tried multiple ways to do it, still no result. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: create 2 nested forms and use `CollectionType`. Hope it helps.

```
<?php

// Controller

$attributes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Attribute::class)->findBy(['code' => 'productstatus']);
$form = $this->createForm(AttributeForm::class, ['attributes' => $attributes]);

// AttributeForm

$builder
    ->add('attributes', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => AttributeValueForm::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ]);

// AttributeValueForm

$builder
    ->add('value', TextType::class, ['label' => false, 'required' => false])
    ->add('active', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => false, 'required' => false])

// Twig view

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% for attribute in form.attributes.children %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_widget(attribute.value) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(attribute.active) }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use an if statement in the your AttributeType like in the example below:

```
$builder
    ->add('entree', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'cantineBundle:plat',
  'choice_label'=>function($plat){
      if($plat->getType()=='Entree'&&$plat->getStatus()=="non reserve"){
           return $plat->getNomPlat();
      }
  },
  'multiple'=>false)
);
```